# Is it possible to watch test execution video of AWS Device Farm in real time?

Tags: mobile, automated-tests, aws-device-farm

I like to be able to project aws device farm test execution video while it's running the test. Would that be possible?

And if yes, would it be possible via API, I don't want to view the execution via the aws console. I would like to execute using rest api (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and then using API pull the streaming video and project it on screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. We do not support this functionality today and we do not have any plans in near future to support this.

Please follow the AWS forum announcements for feature releases
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193&start=0